# Caracteres unicode con escape en texto de PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

Tengo un JSON donde aparece una clave precio y quiero limpiar esa clave y dejar solo la cantidad, pero no encuentra lo que busco porque contiene caracteres especiales.

Lo estoy haciendo en PHP con la función `str_replace`.  Supongo ya que si busco algo sin caracteres especiales lo encuentra y lo reemplaza correctamente.

```
foreach(json_decode($a, true) as $key => $array){
    
    $r1[$key] = str_replace('\u00a0\u20ac','',$array);
        
}
```

Y aquí un caso como está en el JSON, donde aparece el precio y el caracter que quiero eliminar.

```
"precio":"3500\u00a0\u20ac "
```

Answer (score 0):

Para interpretar puntos de código unicode en [comillas dobles](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), se usa el siguiente escape:

```
\u{00a0}
```

Sólo faltaba poner en comillas dobles y agregar las llaves

```
echo "\u{00A0}\u{20AC}"
// -->   €
```

Comment: ok, funciona, gracias